# Does a concave polygon always include a convex poligon?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, proof-writing

Does a concave n-gon, for $n\geq 3$ always include a convex polygon? Rather simplified, a triangle? I have defined break as breaking a convex polygon to a concave one from numerous points, like take a regular pentagon and break it from 2 points. I have taken a convex n-gon and observed that it includes $n-2$ triangles, I have also observed that I can break it maximally from $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right \rfloor$ points. And that the number of triangles it includes don't change. Thus yes. Although I don't know how to prove my observations and whether I can find a counter example or sth. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, I only know every simple polygon with more than $3$ vertices has at least two ears (aka [two ears theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_ears_theorem))

Comment: Can we find a concave poligon such that no three vertices combined form a triangle?

Comment: The two ears theorem states that if $n > 3$, then there are at least two vertices $v$ such that the line segment between the two neighbors of $v$ lies entirely in the interior of the polygon.

Comment: One consequence of the theorem achille hui mentioned, is that any simple polygon with $n$ vertices can always be triangulated into $n-2$ triangles.

Comment: That gave me sight on the number of triangles they include and how to prove it. Though there's still a problem with $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ number of breakable points. How can one prove that?